# Bokeh Server Plot not updating and throwing warning when I use show(plot)

Tags: python, bokeh

[image]I am projecting two different values using select X attribute on Bokeh layout.

There is similar post on SO that tells you to change `from bokeh.layouts import row` to `from bokeh.layouts import column` as well as changing `layout = row(select_widget, plot)` to `layout = column(select_widget, plot)`. I tried this but nothing is happening.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import row

df = pd.read_csv("C:\Python\SpendMap.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

df_construction = df[df['SubCategory'] == 'Constr']

source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x' : df_construction['Year'],
    'y' : df_construction['Spend'],
    'x1': df_construction['Plant']
     })

plot = figure()
plot.diamond('x','y', source=source, color ='red')
select_widget = Select(options = ['Plant','Year'], value='Year', title = 'select new x axis attribute')

def callback(attr, old, new):
    if new == 'Plant':
        data.data = {'x' : df_construction['Year'], 'y':  df_construction['Spend']}
    else:
        data.data = {'x': df_construction['Plant'], 'y': df_construction['Spend']}
        select_widget.on_change('value',callback)

layout = row(select_widget, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

When running bokeh serve --show Plant.py the browser should open and show me Plant and Year on Bokeh when I select drop down on layout but shows only "Year" information.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit data.data. You should edit source.data since this is the source you are using for the glyphs. I wasn't able to reproduce the Models should not be a document root error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import row

df_construction = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004], 'y': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90], 'x1': [2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000]})
source = ColumnDataSource(df_construction)

plot = figure()
plot.diamond('x','y', source=source, color ='red')
select_widget = Select(options = ['Plant','Year'], value='Year', title = 'select new x axis attribute')

def callback(attr, old, new):
    if new == 'Plant':
        source.data = {'x' : df_construction['x1'], 'y':  df_construction['y'], 'x1': df_construction['x']}
    else:
        source.data = {'x' : df_construction['x'], 'y':  df_construction['y'], 'x1': df_construction['x1']}

select_widget.on_change('value',callback)
layout = row(select_widget, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Code for in a Jupyter Notebook (Tested with Bokeh 1.0.3 and 1.0.4):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row

output_notebook()

def modify_doc(doc):
    df_construction = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'x': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004], 'y': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90], 'x1': [2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000]})
    source = ColumnDataSource(df_construction)

    plot = figure()
    plot.diamond('x','y', source=source, color ='red')
    select_widget = Select(options = ['Plant','Year'], value='Year', title = 'select new x axis attribute')

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if new == 'Plant':
            source.data = {'x' : df_construction['x1'], 'y':  df_construction['y'], 'x1': df_construction['x']}
        else:
            source.data = {'x' : df_construction['x'], 'y':  df_construction['y'], 'x1': df_construction['x1']}

    select_widget.on_change('value',callback)
    layout = row(select_widget, plot)
    doc.add_root(layout)

show(modify_doc, notebook_url='localhost:8891') #Change this if it refuses websocket connection
```

Comment: Hi Jasper it still gives an error when I use show(plot )  and copy your code exactly as is.WARNING:bokeh.core.validation.check:W-1004 (BOTH_CHILD_AND_ROOT): Models should not be a document root if they are in a layout box: Figure(id='488cf163-29f0-4cca-b3ca-56f2d504aa67', ...)

Comment: Hey, it looks like you were using a Jupyter notebook in the screenshot you provided, so I also tried it in a notebook to see if I could reproduce your error. I still wasn't able to get the same error unfortunately so I'm not really sure what's going on. You could try the code I used in my notebook (added it to my answer) and check the version of Bokeh you're using. I've tested the code with version 1.0.3 and 1.0.4. Another option would be testing the first code I provided without a Jupyter notebook by running it from the terminal (bokeh serve --show script.py)

Comment: Hi Jasper, you are right. When I updated everything its running well.